# Is it bad practice to store a ref inside redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it bad practice to store parent ref inside redux store ? If so could you please point it out why?
My current task is that I have scrollable container as a parent component and it has many deep children components, some of them are fifth level, and I need to control this parent scrollable container from child component. Of course I can pass down through children, but through redux it would be much convenient.

I don't feel that it would be a mistake to use redux state for that, but I came across some articles where people suggested not to, but there was no clear explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The state should consist only of serializable items, see [Can I put functions, promises, or other non-serializable items in my store state?](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state).

> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store.

And for your question, it explains:

> It's technically possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well as interfere with time-travel debugging.

Using `redux-toolkit` you even will get a warning for that.

Ref object is a **non-serializable item**, what worse it doesn't persist when you unmount components which may cause undefined behaviors.

On the other hand, using Context API for passing `ref` is a good enough solution. Although I would rethink the design and use [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) for some layers (passing ref to the fifth level is certainly a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20code,%2C%20developer%2C%20and%20development%20methodology.&text=It%20is%20also%20a%20term%20used%20by%20agile%20programmers.)).

Comment: Thank you for your quite good response. This is definitely helpful!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the ref object itself is entirely serializable.  It's the content that you put at `refObj.current` that is potentially not serializable, such as a DOM node.